# Absolute convergence, conditional or divergence? $\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$$

This seems fairly simple to me, I know I can look at the absolute value and if that diverges than I am done.

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$$
$p-$ series says that this diverges. Done.

The answer is wrong though, why?

Comment: If the question is "Is the following series *absolutely convergent* ?" then the correct answer is "no, it is not", and you've provided the reason. If they (your teacher, some book, some site) say otherwise then either you copied the wrong question, or you looked under the wrong question's solution, or they are just wrong.

Comment: Edited to clarify the question.

Comment: Oh, that's way another thing: the correct answer is "the series is conditionally convergent since it is a Leibniz Series, but it is not absolutely convergent by the $\,p-$series test", say"

Comment: Good editing, Babak: much clearer now.

Comment: @DonAntonio But I just proved that it diverges with a p series test.

Comment: the proof you gave **must** have been for the absolute value series as it applies only to positive series! So yes, with it you can see that the series of $\,\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]n}\right|=\frac1{\sqrt[3]n}\;$ diverges, but for the original, alternating series you can **not** use this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given series converges, since:

$$(1)\;\;\;\frac1{\sqrt[3]n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{monotonically descendent}$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\text{The series has alternating signs and is thus a Leibniz Series}$$

The given series does **not** converge absolutely since

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]n}\right|=\frac1{\sqrt[3]n}\ge\frac1n\implies\;\text{ the comparison test gives us divergence}$$

Comment: Oh that was stupid of me, I knew this.

Comment: Don't worry: it's happened here or there to us all.

Answer (score 4):

The series is NOT *absolutely* convergent, as you found using the p-series test.

Recall, your series would be **absolutely convergent** *if and only if* the following series were convergent: $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \Big|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\Big| = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$$ But as you observe, **this** series does not converge.

But our given series is an *alternating series*, and as such, we can check to see if it satisfies the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test): it *does*; i.e., it satisfies the *Leibniz test*. Hence it is **conditionally convergent.**

Comment: Still working on your dueling skills I see! Arg! :-) +1

Comment: I am back right now from the uni. Good to see you on a roll. +